# super function in Python

Tags: python, django

Wrt to the code snippet below, why is `super().__init__` used in the model? How does it work?

model.py

```
class DuckForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Duck
        fields = ('description', 'name')

    def __init__(self, community, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.community = community

    def save(self, commit=True):
        duck = super().save(commit=False)
        if not duck.community_id:
            duck.community = self.community

        if commit:
            duck.save()
        return duck
```

views.py

```
def add_duck(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DuckForm(request.animal.community, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            duck = form.save()
            return redirect('DuckData')
    else:
        form = DuckForm(request.user.community)
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'MyDuck.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Are you sure the `__init__` is part of the meta-class? Usually you call `super()` to process the behavior of the super class.

Comment: Yeah, I assume the indentation is incorrect; if you un-tab `__init__` it works as expected.

Comment: Yes, it was incorrect. Got it edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `super.method` calls the `method` method of the parent class, in this case `ModelForm`. This is necessary in this case because Django models and forms have all sorts of strange things that happen to them in the `__init__` method, and if you don't call `super().__init__()` those won't happen and the object won't behave as expected.

Also as a side note, this is invalid syntax in python 2 (but completely valid and correct in python 3). You would have to write `super(DuckForm, self).__init__` to achieve the same goal.